# Recommendations for building a windows dll

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

I am trying to create a Windows dll out of a few visual c++ projects that I am working on. My larger goal is to create a dll that can be linked by clients without worrying(too much) about the nuances of how my dll was compiled.

- I would like to understand better if there are a few basic compiler flags that I should use that is broadly acceptable.
- Are there generally accepted procedures for how struct should be written if I need to export out of the Dll. Especially something that wouldn't be too sensitive to packing alignments. The client might have a 4byte packing, or something else for their own project. How to make sure that doesn't affect if my headers are 8byte aligned.
- Does creating a win32 dll or MFC dll matter.

I did structure my project such that classes are exported based on the ideas mentioned here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Comment: DLLs introduce a large restriction on your interface. A DLL's interface is essentially reduced down to C, so you really need to have a great reason to use a DLL to justify the penalty.

Comment: Everything in the linked article is accurate, hard to see what you want to know beyond this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Any thoughts on creating a win32 dll versus MFC dll. Is there an overhead on creating MFC dll if I don't really need the MFC libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Some point witch crosses my mind.

1. Do not use stl objects in public method signatures or structs.
2. If possible use only simple data types in your signatures.
3. If you have to export some structs, define the packing in the header.

Comment: I do pack my struct. But I encountered a strange problem described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592775/pointers-and-release-build-in-visual-studio). Not sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Best Practices for Creating DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx), this is basic stuff but often ignored issues that can lead to very ugly side effects.